# Workflow for working on www-data owned files

Tags: permissions

What is the best workflow for working on PHP Webpages (local) in "Ubuntu Desktop".
My problem is, when i logIn with my Ubuntu Account, and when i open a php file "geany" i cannot save the file any more,
because the file is owned by "www-data".
Is there a way to open "www-data" owned files -> edit it -> and save them again as www-data?

What is your workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I use `sudo` to support this kind of workflow. It will allow you to execute commands as the user www-data. As an example, if you use `vi` as your text editor, you would use a command like this:

```
sudo -u www-data vi index.php
```

In order to give yourself permission to use `sudo` as the user www-data, you'll need to add the following to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
yourusername ALL=(www-data) ALL
```